# Angular/Javascript Luxon - Convert timestamp changing time to current user timezone

Tags: javascript, angular, luxon

I got a timestamp from the database and I need to display its time in the user's timezone.

**Ex:** Brazil 16:42, France 21:42.

It's a chat, so the messages need to be displayed in each user's time zone.

I have [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html) in the project, but I can not use any of the documentation that helps me in this case.

I have tried to use the methods in some ways

**DateTime.local()** and
**DateTime.setZone(localZone)**

localZone is a variable that receives the local area, for example: "Europe/Paris".

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use luxon [`fromMillis`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefrommillis) to parse timestamp (assuming that it is in milliseconds) or [`fromSeconds`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromseconds) if it is in seconds. You can also pass zone option to create luxon object using given timezone. The you can use [`toFormat()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetoformat) to display time in your desired format. You could have something like the following:

```
DateTime.fromMillis(timestamp, {zone: localZone}).toFormat('HH:mm')
```

If you need, you can also use [`setZone`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimesetzone) to change zone property, here a snippet using sample data:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
let curTimestamp = 1562061791000;
let time = DateTime.fromMillis(curTimestamp)
console.log('Local time:', time.toFormat('HH:mm') );
console.log('Brazil time:',  time.setZone('America/Sao_Paulo').toFormat('HH:mm') );
console.log('France time:', DateTime.fromMillis(curTimestamp, {zone: 'Europe/Paris'}).toFormat('HH:mm') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.16.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

If you want to use Luxon inside Angular view have a look to [luxon-angular](https://github.com/dstelljes/luxon-angular).

Comment: Hello!
I still have problems, schedules are not right, for example. If I send the message at 09:57 in Brazil, when using DateTime.fromMillis(timestamp).setZone('Europe/Paris').toFormat('HH:mm') output is 18:57, but should be 15: 57, correct?
Could it be something in timestamp creation when sending the message? Does luxon have some method that is most recommended to generate this timestamp? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MatheusRufino today at 09:57 in Sao Paolo (Brazil) is 14:57 in Paris (see [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20190702T125700&p1=233&p2=195)). Use [ `toMillis()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-toMillis) to get epoch milliseconds of a luxon object. I don't fully get what is your issue, please try to provide a code sample of your attempt and your desired result, see [mcve]

Comment: Thank's! Now it worked, using the form it gave me. The problem was in the timestamp generated and not the conversion to local time. DateTime.local().toMillis(timestamp) and using DateTime.fromMillis(timestamp).toFormat('HH:mm') worked.